# Is there an alternate way of writing $E[Y]E[X^2] - E[X]E[XY]$?

Tags: probability, least-squares

I've been studying bivariate least squares regression, and I derived the following formula for what the regression line should be:
\begin{align} Y = aX + b, \end{align}
where
\begin{align} a = \frac{E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]}{E[X^2] - E[X]^2}, \end{align}
and
\begin{align} b = \frac{E[Y]E[X^2] - E[X]E[XY]}{E[X^2] - E[X]^2}. \end{align}
The expression for $a$ can be beautifully rewritten as
\begin{align} a = \frac{\text{Cov}(X,Y)}{\text{Var}[X]}, \end{align}
but I can't see a way to write the numerator of $b$ in a simpler form. Is there a way?

Comment: You have $$b = E[Y] - aE[X]$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write :
$$
E[Y]E[X^2] - E[X]E[XY] = (E[Y]E[X^2] - E[Y]E[X]^2) + (E[Y]E[X]^2 - E[X]E[XY]) \\
= E[Y] \mbox{Var}(X) - E[X] \mbox{Cov(X,Y)}
$$

for the numerator of $b$. The denominator is $\mbox{Var}(X)$ so you get :
$$
b = E[Y] - aE[X] = E[Y-aX]
$$

once you take the quotient.  The point of writing $b$ in this form, is (roughly) noting that if $Y=aX+b$(were completely true) then $Y-aX = b$, and taking expectation of both sides gives you $E[Y - aX] = b$. Since the error is two-sided, the estimator will be unbiased, so this relation is to be expected.